# Issue getting latitude and longitude of a given address using google api

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My problem is that running the below function on my local webserver all the addresses passed are resolved by latitude and longitude. When I publish on the host, most of these addresses returns an empty string.
The address argument is so formatted: "Main Street 550, London"

```
    public string GetLongitudeAndLatitude(string address, string sensor)
    {
        string urlAddress = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address) + "&sensor=" + sensor;
        string returnValue = "";
        try
        {
            XmlDocument objXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            objXmlDocument.Load(urlAddress);
            XmlNodeList objXmlNodeList = objXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location");
            foreach (XmlNode objXmlNode in objXmlNodeList)
            {
                // GET LONGITUDE 
                returnValue = objXmlNode.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;

                // GET LATITUDE 
                returnValue += "," + objXmlNode.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Process an error action here if needed  
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: This code could be returning an empty string for any number of reasons. There is a `status` node as part of the response.  That is not being checked.  There may not be any `location` nodes.  The document `Load` may be throwing an exception.  Without knowing any of that information, no useful answer can be given.

Comment: I tried also to check if the status wasn't "OK" with no results. what I do not understand then is the reason for wich on local I can find the coordinates. Thank you for the rapid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the returnValue for each iteration. Change the code to return all the returned latitudes and longitudes to get the complete collection and compare.

```
foreach (XmlNode objXmlNode in objXmlNodeList)
{
    // GET LONGITUDE 
    returnValue += "\r\n" + objXmlNode.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;

    // GET LATITUDE 
    returnValue += "," + objXmlNode.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;
}
```

Also browse to the GoogleMaps url from both your local machine and the server and check if the same XML content is returned?  The server may not have internet connection as well.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Main%20Street%20550,%20London&sensor=false
```

Comment: I did it, the results are the same. On the server I can see the same xml of local (coordinates are loaded I can't retrieve it in the xml).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this other method, but the problem on the server persist triyng to deserialize properties.
The error catched is: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
On local every is ok...

[image]